# Properly spacing div(s) to the left of checkbox(es)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having trouble properly spacing divs to the left of a a checkbox. The intention is to have the user click on the checkbox in a table row and bring up another menu to quickly act on the record. Right now when you click on the checkbox the div is properly spaced to the left but its floats in space. Furthermore, if you click on additional checkboxes it launches in the exact same space. I would like to have the menu appear directly to the left and centered on the checkbox that was clicked. I think I am getting close but I am lost at this point. Thanks in advance for your help.

http://codepen.io/gmrstudios/pen/dNaRLq

```
$("#type-2 a").click(function(e){
   var selector = $('.'+$(this).attr('id'));
    selector.toggle("slow");
  $('div.togg').not(selector).hide();
});
```

[What I am trying to achieve with each checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xh4LZ.jpg)

Thanks for reading...

Comment: create a working example with code editor here.So that we can check and let you know where is the problem.

Comment: Anant, I include the codepen link above. It works but my divs all go to the same place as well as being spaced wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey to make it the way you want first make its parent relative and after that position child element so that it will behave with respect to its parent element.

```
.container-2 { position: relative; }

.type-2 {
  width: 400px;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #b1b1b1;
  border-radius: 7px;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #343434;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: -10px;
  z-index: 9999999;
  font: normal normal 22px Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/quy5vg8c/

Comment: The solution does not seem to work when used with a wide-width screen. Meaning the checkboxes no longer become clickable.

Comment: Also the more you resize the page the further the div gets away from the checkbox.

Comment: Yes. because type-2 box is overlapping on checkbox. So just define particular width to its parent.

Comment: Adding "width: 100px;" works but it also pushes the div to the left. Is there a way to make it respect the width without pushing the div over?

Comment: Much appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to apply relative to `type-2` parent and change position little bit of `type-2`

```
td .container-2{
  position: relative;
}
.type-2 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 70px;
  top: -10px;
}
```

see working demo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vgMEev

Comment: The solution does not seem to work when used with a wide-width screen. Meaning the checkboxes no longer become clickable.

Comment: Also the more you resize the page the further the div gets away from the checkbox.